# Taking hourly Averages Matlab with Vector

Tags: matlab, average

I have a vector in the form of

```
     0   21.3400
     0   22.3000
     1   22.3000
```

The left column is the hour and the right side is the value. I need to calculate the averages for each hour. The problem is that my samples run for longer than 24 hours (multiple days), so it would loop back from 0-23 to 0-23 again. Another problem is that sometimes I am missing samples for a certain hour. For example;

```
   12.0000   29.5000
   14.0000   35.7400
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: So you want to aggregate values for different days or not? Give an example with desired ouput in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part "so it would loop back from 0-23 to 0-23 again" is unclear to me. Maybe you are looking for the modulo function `mod()`. But after you solved this particular problem, your averaging-problem can be taken care off using `accumarray`. It is like the perfect use case for this function.

```
%// your data
data = [
     0   21.3400
     0   22.3000
     1   22.3000
     12.0000   29.5000
     14.0000   35.7400];
 %// group (find subs)
 [hours, b, subs] = unique(data(:,1));

 %// apply function mean to grouped data
 avg = accumarray(subs, data(:,2), [], @mean);
 result = [hours, avg]
```

In `result` the result is stored table-like, the first column are the unique hours and the second column are the averaged datav alues for those hours.

```
result =

     0    21.8200
1.0000    22.3000
12.0000   29.5000
14.0000   35.7400
```

As an example: for the hour `0` the average of the data values `21.3400` and `22.300` is correctly computed as `(21.3400 + 22.300)/2`, which equals `21.8200`.

Comment: Yep, did some searching, accumarray is much better than what I was attempting to do.